# error in .net reflector

Tags: c#, reflector

i have reflected one program with .net reflector and open it in visual studio.
one item in each form is:

```
bool IControlByOptions.get_IsDisposed()
{
  return this.IsDisposed;
}
```

**when i build solution , it has an error :**
`'Solo.Module.CtrlProductForm.Solo.Base.IControlByEdition.get_IsDisposed()' explicit method implementation cannot implement 'Solo.Base.IControlByEdition.IsDisposed.get' because it is an accessor.`

IControlByOptions file contents :

```
using System;

namespace Solo.Base
{
 public interface IControlByOptions
 {
    bool IsDisposed { get; }

    void RefreshUIFromCompanyOrPersonalOptions();
 }
}
```

how to fix this error ?

Comment: You do realize that reverse engineering applications is usually against their license agreement, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the implementation to

```
bool IControlByOptions.IsDisposed
{
    get { return this.IsDisposed; }
}
```

Update based on your comments. Try this for properties with setter.

```
bool ICtrlTemplateOption.Visible
{
    get { return this.Visible; }
    set { this.Visible = value; }
}
```

Comment: bool ICtrlTemplateOption.Visible
    {
        get { return this.Visible; }
    }
    void ICtrlTemplateOption.set_Visible([In] bool obj0)
    {
      this.Visible = obj0;
    }

Comment: namespace Solo.Module
{
  internal interface ICtrlTemplateOption
  {
    bool Visible { get; set; }

    DocTemplateOptions Options { get; }

    void InitOptions(CtrlPrintSettingTemplates parent);

    void SetButtonsPrePreview();

    void SetButtonsPostPreview();

    void SaveCurrentOption();
  }
}