# Error after using .NET decompiler: (...explicit method implementation cannot implement...because it is an accessor)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ilspy

I decompile a code library with [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/), the code is written is C#. When I build solution, this error message comes up and says:

`'.....IEditorVirtualButtonBehaviour.get_gameObject()' explicit method implementation cannot implement '.....IEditorVirtualButtonBehaviour.gameObject.get' because it is an accessor`

**Script.cs**

```
GameObject IEditorVirtualButtonBehaviour.get_gameObject()
{
    return base.get_gameObject();
}
```

**IEditorVirtualButtonBehaviour.cs**

```
GameObject gameObject
{
    get;
}
```

What causes that to have error? How do I fix it?

PS: [A possible duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24445085/error-in-net-reflector), it doesn't solve the problem, I'd definitely read the post before I submitted this question.

Comment: What have you changed after reading the "duplicate" to make it distinct?  As the question stands it seems to be the same problem.

Comment: @DStanley `GameObject IEditorVirtualButtonBehaviour.gameObject(){ get { return base.gameObject(); } }`

Comment: Take the parens off of `gameObject` : `GameObject IEditorVirtualButtonBehaviour.gameObject{ get { return base.gameObject(); } }`  That might not be the only change; if you provide more code in your question to make it distinct then a different solution might become apparent.

Comment: @DStanley Oh silly me, the error is gone. But the error still appear on this line of code: `void IEditorVirtualButtonBehaviour.enabled(bool enabled) { set {return base.enabled(enabled); } }`

Comment: take the parens off that one as well - there's an implicit `value` parameter:  Use `void IEditorVirtualButtonBehaviour.enabled { set { base.enabled = value; } }`  Note that there is probably a `get_` method that needs to be added as the getter for that property (set-only properties are very rare).

Comment: Seems like you're either unclear about how property getters and setters work of you aren't taking much time to think about the problem.  I would be VERY hesitant to recompile decompiled code and assume that it works the way it originally did.  What is your end goal?  Why are you reverse-engineering this code anyways?

Comment: If the duplicate isn't helpful, you should explain why. Someone very experienced in C# thinks they're the same question, so you should explain why it isn't. What's different in your situation? Is there something in the duplicate you don't understand?

Comment: @DStanley This is actually an asset for a game engine called Unity, I can simply change the variable if it is public. But some of those are private variables, if I change those to public, I might have more customizable variable in my game. By the way, the original line is: `void IEditorVirtualButtonBehaviour.get_enabled(bool enabled) { return base.set_enabled(enabled); } }`, and in **IEditorVirtualButtonBehaviour.cs**: `bool enabled { get; set; }`. It doesn't work just now, probably something still wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `get_gameObject` method entirely. The compiler will implement the property using the base method. ILSpy apparently doesn't recognize it's dealing with an inherited property getter here, possibly because the base class implements the interface explicitly.